# What do you expect to see when you click an order's item?

Tags: website-design, web-app, tables, e-commerce, user-expectation

we are building a site in which you can purchase products, virtual products and virtual courses.
Now the 'My Purchases' page got some complications. We are displaying the orders in a table with the following headers:

1. Order ID
2. Order Date
3. Product Name (each order has only 1 product)
4. type (course, virtual, etc)
5. Price
6. Quantity
7. Total
8. Access (if the order is a course or a virtual, there will be a button to view/download)
9. Review (reviews can happen only if the user purchased the item, so here will be a button 'Review' or a label 'you already wrote a review')

Now, when you click the product name (the only field that is a link), what should happen?

- Go to the product page (the one with the description, images) ?
- Go to the Order Details page (because it doesn't have a link to it, yet) ?
- Any of the above, but if its a course or virtual, take him to the view/download page, thus removing the need for the 'access' header field

Maybe the Order ID should be a link, too?

Any insight on how to improve this table will be of great help.

Note: the max. width of the table is 1115px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would link the Order ID to the Order Details page. Just seems logical to me.

I think I would want the link to act the way you describe item 8 - Access. I'm not sure why you would need to go to a product description page after you have purchased the item. In theory, you know what you have purchased. However, I would also assume that from the page that allows you to download the item, or start the video, you would have either the product description here or a link to it.

I think you can save the Access column.

Comment: Thanks Mark, good idea. I'll do it that way.  But tell me,  the review field seems logical to you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the review field seems logical". If you are you asking if it seems logical to have it in the table? I don't think it is a problem. Are you going to have a star rating, or comments, or a combination of both like Amazon? Personal preference here, but I like the Amazon model. Star ratings do not convey enough info, and comments can be ignored. On Amazon, I look at the star rating with the comment, and decide if the comment is worth reading (i.e. user gave 3/5 stars, now I want to know why).

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of the first answer -- the link to Order Details points to the product detail page, which has a full description, reviews, specs, etc., AND a button to Buy/Download. Your table is sort of like an order-confirmation, or wish list. See example below

[image: Amazon Wishlist]

The table serves as a record of items ordered or purchased.

As for the Review link, is there a clear path back to the My Purchases page that contains the table? You will get some reviews by customers who return to the table, but you will have to prompt most others to provide reviews. Maybe when they complete an online course, you could pop a notice with something like "Congratulations on Completing Course XYZ! What did you think of the course? Give us a quick review."